# Visibility of tcp connections of containers from the host

Tags: linux, ubuntu, containers, lxc, linux-containers

On plain lxc (not docker or any other flavor), is there a way to see the tcp connections and socket allocations of containers from the host from the command line - perhaps a netstat option or an lxc-command?  We are using ubuntu for both the host and containers.

Answer (score 1):

you could use lxc-netstat for this job

https://manned.org/lxc-netstat/01c5f51e

HTHs

Thanks,

//P